# Repainting Frame erases previously drawn shape

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm currently working with painting in Java and have run into an issue with repaint() erasing the previously drawn shape. Here is an example of my issue:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        click.paintPiece(g);
    }
```

---

```
public void paintPiece(Graphics g) {
        int x = (getMouseX())*70 + 10;
        int y = mover.getRow()*70 + 10;
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
```

Every time the mouse is clicked, the paintPiece() method is called within the paintComponent() method. The problem I have encountered from this is that the previously drawn oval is erased when the new oval is created. Something also to note is that on each mouse click I am repainting the window. How can I paint a new oval without erasing the previously drawn one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Solution 1: Create an `ArrayList<Ellipse2D>` and fill it with a new item on mouse click. In your `paintComponent(...)` method, iterate through the List, drawing each shape.
- Solution 2: Draw your ovals onto a BufferedImage using its Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on the BufferedImage, and then draw that BufferedImage in your paintComponent method. Don't forget to dispose of the BI's Graphics object when done using it.